# Date Field MUI6 date style issue

Tags: javascript, material-ui, datefield

I am trying to update Date Field's style but I am unable to update. Please refer screenshot, There is a gap between date and / (slash). Can we remove it from Date Field.
I am also sharing link below for [reference](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-field/)
[image]

I am expecting to no gap between number and /.

Thanks for your support.